# Transform a String with unicode escaped character to normal string (without escaped characters)

Tags: java, unicode, escaping

Is there something already done to do the following. What I need is a utility class that already implements **convertEscapedUTFStringToNormalString** for this example or if there isn't something done then how can I do it?

```
@Test
public void testConvertEscapedUTFStringToNormalString() {
    String expected = "Hello World!";

    String escaped = "Hello World\\u0021";
    String unescaped = convertEscapedUTFStringToNormalString(escaped);

    assertEquals(expected, unescaped);
}



private String convertEscapedUTFStringToNormalString(String escaped) {
    //TODO: unimplemented
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at Apache Commons? Their StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava does what you want, I think. (http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: Many, many thanks! This is exactly what I needed and it´s not so easy to find the answer.